# Sencha Touch: Maxium call stack size exceeded (google maps)

Tags: google-maps, sencha-touch

I've been trying to get google maps to work on my sencha touch page but it just won't work.
Ive found a lot of topics on this problem, but I can't seem to find the problem in my code. Basically at the moment I'm trying to put a marker on my current location with google maps. Later I will try to show a route based on a given adress. But when I open the page I only see the interface elements of the map. It keeps saying the following in my element inspector in chrome:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
ze
F.get
F.get
(anonymous function)
F.transform_changed
ag
ag
F.set
Rs.(anonymous function).ta
F.aa
Qh.(anonymous function).l
(anonymous function)
O.trigger
F.aa
Qh.(anonymous function).l
(anonymous function)
O.trigger
F.aa
Qh.(anonymous function).l
(anonymous function)
O.trigger
```

I just noticed I am also getting the following messages in element inspector:

```
Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type font/woff: "http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/roboto/v9/Hgo13k-tfSpn0qi1SFdUfT8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff".
Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type font/woff: "http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/roboto/v9/2UX7WLTfW3W8TclTUvlFyQ.woff".
Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type font/woff: "http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/roboto/v9/RxZJdnzeo3R5zSexge8UUT8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff".
```

The code in my view is as follows:

```
Ext.define('Sencha.view.Tournaments', {

    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'tournamentPage',
    config: {
        title: 'maps',
        layout: 'fit'
    },

    initialize : function() {
        var lat, lng;
        var geoLocationOptions = {
            maximumAge: 3000, 
            timeout: 5000, 
            enableHighAccuracy: true
        };
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoLocationSuccess,geoLocationError,geoLocationOptions);

        function geoLocationSuccess(position) {
            lat = position.coords.latitude;
            lng = position.coords.longitude;
        }

        function geoLocationError() {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Error','Error while getting geolocation');
        }
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
        map = this.add({
            xtype: 'map',
            getLocation: true,
            autoLoad: true,
            mapOptions: {
                zoom: 15,
                center: position,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                navigationControl: true,
                zoomControl: true,
                mapTypeControl: true,
                scrollwheel: true,
                scaleControl: true,
                zoomControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE
                }
            }
        });

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            id: 'geoLocMarker',
            position: position,
            map: map.getMap(),
            visible: true
        });
    }



})
```

I hope I'm not asking to stupid of a question, I'm trying to learn! I've been going at it for a while now and it just does not seem to work! Thanks in advance.